# NSMutableArray gets dealloc halfway through block

Tags: objective-c, malloc, automatic-ref-counting

I have an `NSMutableArray` getting populated with values within a enumerateObjects loop. About the 4th or 5th time the function to populate the MutableArray is getting called, I get a `SIGSEGV` error with the stack

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x39e7e626 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation 0x2f663dc9 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 154
2   libobjc.A.dylib 0x39e83b6b _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 172
3   MyAppName 0x0004bdff -[BluetoothManager(DataParse) processResponse:] (BluetoothManager+DataParse.m:231)
```

Setup

1. An `appDelegate` which has a strong pointer to `BluetoothManager` instance.
2. A function call on `BluetoothManager` class, with the signature  `processResponse:` on BluetoothManager which is invoked every time `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` is called on the peripheral delegate.
3. `processBleResponse:` takes an NSData blob and converts it into an array of NSNumbers

What I'm noticing is that the 4th time or so that `processReponse:` is called, the mutable Array in which I store all my NSNumbers gets malloc'd within its own enumerateObjects loop.

I've simulated the test with a repeating NSTimer which invokes processResponse: every 30-40s with some dummy data, but the error is reproducible after every few iterations of the loop. The overall memory usage of the app is not spiking over 45MB

```
// method on BluetoothManager class 
- (void)processBleResponse:(NSData *)myData
{   
__block float baseValue = 34.500;
__block float incrementValue = 0.0500;

// convert hex data into array of 10 binary "strings"
NSArray *individualBinaryArray = [self extractBinaryValues:myData];

// Extract temperature fields
NSIndexSet *relevantIndices = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, individualBinaryArray.count - 1)];

__block NSUInteger indexOfFailure = NSNotFound;
NSMutableArray *decimalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[individualBinaryArray enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:relevantIndices options:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString *hexString = [self hexString:(NSString *)obj];

    if (hexString.length)
    {
        NSScanner *decimalScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
        unsigned int decimalValue = 0;

        if ([decimalScanner scanHexInt:&decimalValue])
        {
            // insert value
            // THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS
            [decimalValues addObject:@(baseValue + incrementValue * decimalValue)];
        }
        else
        {               
            // throw alert/exception etc.   
            *stop = YES;
            indexOfFailure = idx;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *stop = YES;
        indexOfFailure = idx;
    }       
}];

// Insert list of NSNumbers into CoreData
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the problem is the object that this method belongs to (rather than the array). Make sure that's not getting deallocated prematurely. FYI, I'm unable to reproduce the crash on the basis of this code sample.

Comment: might be. I realized that I'm using UIImage imageNamed to load a lot of one-time-only images, which get retained in the internal imageIO stack - over 9.7 MB of wasted space. I've cut this down for now, will need to look at failing more gracefully regardless. Thanks